# Returning Wingdings characters within a text with an Excel formula

Tags: excel, text, excel-formula, wingdings

I want return appropriated Wingdings character at end of a string, with a formula as shown below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjEh1.jpg)

Which formula can I write to return the shown Wingdings characters at the end of the regular string in a cell? (Instead of "?" character): *Solid circle* character for return in true situation of formula and *hollow circle* character return in false situation, so these two characters are in green range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A formula alone cannot change the font of *part* of a cell.**

The best you could do is have a VBA function to make the change as needed, which you could run manually, or perhaps assign to a button, timer, event, etc.

This sub changes the last character of the currently active cell to Wingdings:

```
Sub LastLettWingding_Active()
    'changes the font for the last character of the **active** cell
    ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=Len(ActiveCell), Length:=1).Font.Name = "Wingdings"
End Sub
```

...and this one does the same thing, but to the currently **selected** cell or range of cells:

```
Sub LastLettWingding_Selection()
    'changes the font for the last character of the all selected cells
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Application.Selection
        c.Characters(Start:=Len(c), Length:=1).Font.Name = "Wingdings"
    Next c
End Sub
```

---

### Edit:

I didn't realize it's a formula result that you're trying to format part of.

Unfortunately, **Neither a formula *nor* VBA can change the font of *part* of a formula result.**

My only suggestion would be to automate a `Copy` + `Paste Values` to a different cell, change the partial-formatting of *that* cell with the function above, and perhaps "hide" the original (formula) cell.

### Edit #2:

Oh yeah-- @TomSharpe's also made the think that Unicode symbols might be an easier solution (included in most fonts, instead of using a separate font without the alphabet).

✂ ✃ ✄ ✅ ✆ ✇ ✈ ✉ ✊ ✋ ✌ ✍ ✎ ✏ ✐ ✲ ✳ ✴ ✵ ✶ ✷ ✸ ✹ ✺ ✻ ✼ ✽ ✾ ✿ ❀ ❁ ❂ ❃ ❄ ❅ ❆ ❇ ❈ ❉ ❊ ❋ ❌ ➮ ➯ ➰ ➱ ➲ ➳ ➴ ➵ ➶ ➷ ➸ ⌚ ⌛ ❶ ❷ ❸ ❹ ❺ ● ◌ ○ ◊ ◦ □ ┘ ⌂ ⅕⃝ Ω ℗ Ө Ӂ Φ ʘ ʘ ① ② ③ ④ ⑤ etc.

Click an empty cell and then on the `Insert` tab, click `Symbol`.  Make sure you're on a "regular" font (like Calibri) and scroll way down the list.

Double click the one(s) you want, then `Insert`.

Highlight the symbol now showing in the formula bar, copy from there, and *now* you can paste it into your `IF` formula.

(Or, just copy copy the symbols from above right into an Excel formula...)

Comment: With regards, `Start` parameter in above only works with `Start:=1` and do change string entirely, as when the value of appropriated cell is returned with a formula. So It works on specific character, only when the string is static and not returned with a formula.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a fair approximation to it by using char(149) •
 / lower case o in one of the regular fonts

```
=IF(VALUE(RIGHT(C4,1))>=5,"Selected "&CHAR(149),"Selected o")
```

Comment: Good point, I was focused on the font part not the symbol part of the question! On that thought, there's also plenty of Unicode symbols that will work with a standard font

Comment: Regards. Above [ashleedawg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8112776/ashleedawg)'s approached helped me, because or preferring better format, (so consuming performance).